# How can I add a key to MariaDB table that already contains data?

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I'm trying to alter my table with MySQL but it will show an error on ALTER:

> #1062 - Duplicate entry '5009-daring-1' for key 'doctermitem'

**SQL query:**

```
ALTER TABLE `wpi4_asp_index`
  ADD UNIQUE KEY `doctermitem` (`doc`,`term`,`blogid`),
  ADD KEY `term_ptype_bid_lang` (`term`(20),`post_type`(20),`blogid`,`lang`(10)),
  ADD KEY `rterm_ptype_bid_lang` (`term_reverse`(20),`post_type`(20),`blogid`,`lang`(10))
```

How can I solve this error?

Comment: You are trying create `doctermitem` as `UNIQUE KEY`, but already there are duplicate entry exist in that combination, so it not allowing to add the `doctermitem` column as `UNIQUE KEY`

Comment: *"how can i solve this error ?"* to add to @Arulkumar 's comment you will have to "manually" find and remove the duplicates, there should be topics about that already on stackoverflow.

Comment: Meanwhile, don't use "prefix indexing" (eg, `term(20)`), it is virtually useless.  Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE wpi4_asp_index` if you need to discuss this further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying create `doctermitem` as `UNIQUE KEY`, but already there are duplicate entry exist in that combination (as you mentioned '5009-daring-1'), so it is not allowing to add the `doctermitem` as `UNIQUE KEY`.

You need to manually remove those duplicate combination values, then it will allow to create the `UNIQUE KEY`

Answer (score 1):

The columns you're targeting for a unique key are not unique - there is at least one row which is duplicated, there may be more.

Find them through a SQL statement:

```
select doc,
      term,
      blogid,
      count(*)
from wpi4_asp_index
group by doc,
      term,
      blogid
having count(*) > 1
```

You will then have to decide what the problem is and how to fix it. Broadly speaking, there are two likely causes:

- You have incorrect data. Fix the data, e.g. by deleting the duplicates.
- Your assumptions about uniqueness are wrong - you may need to add an additional column to your unique key.